# How do I find the sequence of the phage BxB1 gene?

Tags: genetics, sequence-analysis, recombination

Specifically, I'm trying to find the sequence of BxB1 and its att sites.  I have success finding the att site sequences, but I'm having a bit more of an issue with finding the sequence of the actual recombinase.  I've looked through Genebank, but I can't find a definitive sequence of the BxB1 recombinase.

How should I go about looking for this sequence?

EDIT: One more thing I'm concerned about is the validity of the sequences that I do find.  For example, I have seen that Addgene has this [pCAG-NLS-HA-Bxb1](https://www.addgene.org/browse/sequence/77884/) sequence.  However, I'm not sure how to verify that this sequence is correct.

Comment: [The](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AF271693.1) genome has the gene annotated. [This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/JQ305141.1) plasmid has the gene.

Answer (score 1):

http://phagesdb.org/phages/Bxb1/ here you can click "Locally BLAST this genome" it will give you the sequence in FASTA format and then you can click BLAST if you want additional information about the sequence, alignment, etc